# How to allow Salesforce Community User to view records submitted by other users

Tags: community, sharing, customer-community, permission-sets, community-builder

I want to allow community users to view records submitted by other users. At present the community users are having Customer Community Plus License.

I have created two different profiles for community users with Customer Community Plus License

1. Judge Profile
2. Applicant Profile

The users with Judge Profile should see records submitted by all Applicant Profile users.

[image]

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

With the Customer Community Plus licences you can use the standard Organisational Wide Defaults and Sharing Rules to do this. You will either need to use Roles or Public groups to do this. If you create Applicant and Judge Roles then assign all users with that profile to the role that may be easiest.

Make the OWD for the Applicant object as Private by going to Setup>Administer>Security Controls>Sharing Settings>Organization Wide Defaults and setting the Default External Access to Private.

[image]

Then you can set up a Sharing Rule on the object, I've used Account here, but it works the same way for any other object. You can base it on the roles as you are using Customer Community Plus. The record owner role would be Applicant and the role to share with would be Judge.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late, thanks a lot for your answer. I'm working on with your approach.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to create user roles for external users (community users). I could see the external users are automatically given a role on their account name. Even though the users have Customer Community Plus license, I could not change their role.

Comment: Correction on that - the Customer Community Plus users will inherit their role from the associated Account for the Contact record. I'll have to do a little more testing and update the answer with the details.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to assign them a different role? Thanks in advance.